# Having trouble with my arduino

Tags: c#, arduino

sorry for the vague title but i didn't know what to put because i don't actually know what my problem is. Iv'e written some code for a motion sensor connected to an arduino. Everytime i run the script it bypasses the while loop i marked for some reason and then executes the code below it and stops.

```
int buzzPin = 8;
int upPin = 7;
int downPin = 6;
int motionPin = 12;
int redLed = 4;
int amberLed = 3;
int greenLed = 2;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buzzPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(amberLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(upPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(downPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(motionPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(amberLed, LOW);
  while(!digitalRead(upPin)==HIGH); //this is just bypassed when 'upPin' is not high
  if(digitalRead(upPin)==HIGH){
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(amberLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);  //delay before arming the motion sensor
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(250);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
    } //stops here...
    while(!digitalRead(motionPin)==HIGH);
    disarm();
    alarm();
}

bool disarm(){ //button combination to disarm the motion sensor and stop the alarm
  int i = 0;
  while(true){
    while(digitalRead(upPin)||digitalRead(downPin));
    while(!digitalRead(upPin)||!digitalRead(downPin)){i++; 
    delay(1000);
    if(i == 5){
      return(false);
      }
    }
    if(digitalRead(upPin)==HIGH){
      int i = 0;
      }
    else{continue;}
    while(digitalRead(upPin)||digitalRead(downPin));
    while(!digitalRead(upPin)||!digitalRead(downPin)){i++; 
    delay(1000);
    if(i == 5){
      return(false);
      }
    }
    if(digitalRead(upPin)==HIGH){
      int i = 0;
      }
    else{continue;}
    while(digitalRead(upPin)||digitalRead(downPin));
    while(!digitalRead(upPin)||!digitalRead(downPin)){i++; 
    delay(1000);
    if(i == 5){
      return(false);
      }
    }
    if(digitalRead(downPin)==HIGH){
      int i = 0;
      }
    else{continue;}
    while(digitalRead(upPin)||digitalRead(downPin));
    while(!digitalRead(upPin)||!digitalRead(downPin)){i++; 
    delay(1000);
    if(i == 5){
      return(false);
      }
    }
    if(digitalRead(upPin)==HIGH){
      int i = 0;
      }
    else{continue;}
    while(digitalRead(upPin)||digitalRead(downPin));
    while(!digitalRead(upPin)||!digitalRead(downPin)){i++; 
    delay(1000);
    if(i == 5){
      return(false);
      }
    }
    if(digitalRead(downPin)==HIGH){
      int i = 0;
      }
    else{continue;}
    while(digitalRead(upPin)||digitalRead(downPin));
    while(!digitalRead(upPin)||!digitalRead(downPin)){i++; 
    delay(1000);
    if(i == 5){
      return(false);
      }
    }
    if(digitalRead(downPin)==HIGH){
      int i = 0;
      }
    else{continue;}
    break;
    }
  return(true);
  delay(50);
  return(false);
  }

  void alarm(){
    digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(amberLed, LOW);
    while(disarm()==false){
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(buzzPin, LOW);
      delay(500);
      }
    }
```

If anyone could tell me what my problem is and how to fix it that would be great.

Comment: I think you need to post a picture of your wiring.

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried `while(digitalRead(upPin)!=HIGH);` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your loop()

(which isn't a loop, but an awful long lasting collection of non-interruptible delays)

does this:

```
 void loop() {
    show_green();
    hang_until(upPin, LOW); // this can last forever
    show_amber();
    buzz_a_while(); // blocks a couple of seconds
    hang_until(motionPin, LOW); // this seems to last forever
    disarm();
    alarm();
    delay(1 sec);
}
```

So simply force upPin and motionPin to LOW forever, and you won't notice that "stop".

while() is always suspicious in arduino coding, because it disables the main feature of arduino: run the loop function forever.

Answer (score 0):

You write in the comment for the first while loop that it eill be bypassed if the pin is not high. But then you have a negating operator (!) just before the condition that sure looks strange. I suggest you remove that. The statement just after that also seems unnecessary as it just entered the loop on exactly the condition it checka for.